# Privacy Policy auth dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy-policy

Today I have a "Notice of Violation: Privacy Policy (App ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" on my email from an old app.

How I fix this problem? just adding a privacy policy url ? or generating an auth dialog? or deleting the app? that app it's a image and a fbcomment box to enter a premise for a contest.

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the URL to your Privacy Policy at the `Contact Info` section > `Privacy Policy URL` field:

[image: Privacy Policy URL]

Doing so will make your Privacy Policy link appear on the App Dialog for user consent near the `App Terms`:

[image: Buffer App Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

We got these too. You just add a Privacy Policy URL. Like you, we don't actually use any of the functionality that'd show a privacy policy, we just have the app to create Facebook Feed dialogs.